# Is it true that the Ummah of Yunus (Jonah) is the only one to have all members of it to profess faith in Allah (God)?

Tags: tafseer, ummah, yunus

From [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://www.quranwebsite.com/tafsir%20ibn%20kathir/ibn_010_yunus.html):

> No town has denied the truth and then believed when they saw the
> scourge, and then their belief benefited them, with the exception of
> the people of Yunus. When they lost their Prophet and they thought
> that the scourge was close upon them, Allah sent through their hearts
> the desire to repent. So they wore woolen fabrics and they separated
> each animal from its offspring. They then cried out to Allah for forty
> nights. When Allah saw the truth in their hearts and that they were
> sincere in their repentance and regrets, He removed the scourge from
> them.

Does this imply that each and every individual of that Ummah became a believer?

Is **Prophet Yunus (Jonah)** the only Prophet to have his entire Ummah turn to Allah (esp after he left them without Allah's permission & was eaten alive by a fish only to repent and be forgiven by Allah)?